# Cant install java 8 on window server by chef-solo

Tags: chef-solo

I use cookbooks from https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/java
The code runs on Centos 6, but it doesn't run on windows server.
I get this ERROR

> No download url set for java installer
>
> URI::invalidURIError
>
> ---
>
> bad URI(is not URI)

Answer (score 3):

For Windows, you have to provide the Java installation file yourself, i.e. download the installer and put it somewhere locally.  Then set `node['java']['windows']['url']` to point to the file.

The [documentation](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/java#windows) explains why this is necessary - basically there's no simple way to download the java msi programmatically from Oracle's website.